# logo should be visible only on scroll

Tags: javascript, html

I placed logo in sticky navigation bar. It should be visible only if scroll some 100px.

I tried using reference [Show div after scrolling 100px from the top of the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13195048/show-div-after-scrolling-100px-from-the-top-of-the-page) but its not working for me. 
Can any one please help.

Here is the code

```
<div id="toplogo"><img src="images/logo.png" /></div>
<script>
var navlogo = $("toplogo");
$(window).scroll(function(){
  if($(window).scrollTop() >= 100 ){
       navlogo.show();
  } else {
     navlogo.hide();

  }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your jquery selection is wrong.

var navlogo = $("toplogo");

should be

var navlogo = $("#toplogo");